# Why I get  If I try insert Estonian flag emoji  by unicode codepoint?

Tags: unicode, emoji

I want to insert Estonian flag emoji  by it's unicode codepoint U+1F1EA, but when I press <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and insert the mentioned codepoint, I end up with `REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER E`:

When I investigated, it has indeed the same endpoint U+1F1EA. When I used [What Unicode character is this?](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html), both symbols ( and ) are detected as `REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER E`.

Why?

When I copy flag emoji from [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/flag-estonia/) I get  and when I just insert the codepoint (as defined in Emojipedia page too) I get . It is confusing, that same codepoint results with 2 different symbols, but when detected, they both refer to same codepoint.

I feel I miss something from the picture.

Comment: this about Ubuntu?

Comment: It is, all I use on desktop is Ubuntu, I have no Idea, how it works on Win or Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, for emoji flag I need to insert same codepoint twice like

<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>1f1ea<kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>1f1ea<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: It works for me without `Alt`.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying Unicode representation of  is 2 codepoints in length, not 1. `U+1F1EA` is the codepoint at position `[0]`. Coincidentally, it's also the codepoint at position `[1]`, because the ISO 2-letter country code for Estonia is "EE".

To insert any emoji flag, you need to insert *both* of the region indicator symbols for its country code adjacent to each other. For example:

```
Estonia (EE)  +  = 
Nepal   (NP)  +  = 
Kenya   (KE)  +  =
```

The accepted answer happens to true for Estonia, but not in the general case (most country codes do not contain repeated letters).